# "AdwordsApp" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, account

As the title says I'm getting the error `"AdwordsApp" is not defined` when running my Adwords Script. I'm new to Adwords Script and can't figure out what's wrong. I'm running the script in a single account but this account is in a MCC-account. Can that be the reason?

My code looks like this:

```
var spreadUrl = "xxxxxxx"

function main(){
    var total = 0;

    var campaignSelector = AdwordsApp.campaigns()
        .forDateRange("LAST_MONTH");

    var campaignIterator = campaignSelector.get();

    while(campaignIterator.hasNext()) {
        var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
        var budget = campaign.adGroups.getBudget();
        var budgetAmount = budget.getAmount();
        total += budgetAmount;
    }
}
```

The code is far from ready...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `AdWordsApp.campaigns()` instead of `AdwordsApp.campaigns()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the AdWords Script docs found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/your-first-script), I think the issue is on the following line of code.

```
var campaignSelector = AdwordsApp.campaigns()
```

`AdwordsApp` should be `AdWordsApp`, note the casing of the `w`. Changing that line of code so that it reads:

```
var campaignSelector = AdWordsApp.campaigns()
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks a lot!